# Телеграм бот на питоне отправка стикера пользователем

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

делаю бота на питоне с помощью библиотеки TelegramBotAPI. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на конкретный стикер из стикерпака от бота приходил ответ.

Типа:

- пользователь присылает конкретный стикер
- бот отправляет на него конктерный ответ(например 1)
  на другой стикер бот присылает ответ например 2

я уже извлекал id стикера, но все равно не получалось, может я что то делал не так

Comment: А что конкретно не получатся?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.